# search key pagination issue where should use unset to destroy session when click any link or searching another key

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am searching a key in search bar and then its session store in `session_start();`  now i wanted when i am clicking at any other page or link or refresh any page this search session is not leaving , then how to use to destroy search key session in my code and where should i put unset`($_SESSION['search']);` code in my page to destroy session here is page code

```
<?php unset($_SESSION['search']); 
require_once('inc/top.php');?>
               <body>
               <div id="wrapper">
<?php require_once('inc/header.php');?>
<?php               
                     $total_num_page=1;
                    if(isset($_GET['page']))
                    {
                    $page_id=$_GET['page'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       $page_id=1;
                    }
                  if(isset($_POST['submitSearch']) || $_SESSION['search'])
                    {
                        session_start();
                        if($_POST['submitSearch']){
                            $_SESSION['search']=$_POST['search'];  
                        }
                        $all_post_query= "select * from files where recieved_by like '%". $_SESSION["search"]. "%' or processed_by like  '%".$_SESSION["search"]."%' or   purpose like  '%".$_SESSION["search"]."%' or file_name like  '%".$_SESSION["search"]."%' order by date desc";
                        $all_post_run=mysqli_query($con,$all_post_query);
                        $all_post=mysqli_num_rows( $all_post_run);
                        $total_page=ceil($all_post/$total_num_page);
                        $page_start_from=($page_id-1)*$total_num_page;
                     }
                 else
                 {
                   $all_post_query="select * from files order by date desc";
                   $all_post_run=mysqli_query($con,$all_post_query);
                   $all_post=mysqli_num_rows($all_post_run);
                   $total_page=ceil($all_post/$total_num_page);
                   $page_start_from=($page_id-1)*$total_num_page;
                  }

               ?>
    <div class="container-fluid body-section " style="margin-top:90px;margin-bottom:300px;">
                           <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <h1><i class="fa fa-hand-o-down" aria-hidden="true"> File List </i></h1>
                                <a href="letterfile.php"><button type="button" style=" margin-left:190px; margin-top:-70px;"  class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"> Case for Letter </i></button>
                                </a> 
                                <a href="callfile.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style=" margin-left:210px; margin-top:-70px; background:#880E4F; "><i class="fa fa-phone-square"aria-hidden="true" style="color:white;"><font color="white"> Case for Call</font> </i></button>
                                </a>
                                <a href="dustbinfile.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style=" margin-left:150px; margin-top:-70px;"><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"> Filed Case</i></button>
                                   </a>   
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-7 search-box">
                                        <form  action="index.php" class="search-form" method="post">
                                            <div class="form-group has-feedbacck">
                                            <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Here" />
                                            <input type="submit" class="Goform" name="submitSearch" value="Go!"/>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                                           </div>
                                        </form> 
                                     </div>
                                   <hr>
                                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Id</th>
                                                <th>File-name</th>
                                                <th>Purpose</th>
                                                <th>Recieved-By </th>
                                                 <th>Processed-By</th>
                                                 <th>Adress</th>
                                                 <th>Contact-No</th>
                                                 <th>Date</th>
                                                 <th>Update</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                                            if(isset($_POST['submitSearch']))
                                            {
                                                $search=$_POST['search'];
                                                $p_query="select * from files where recieved_by like '%$search%' or processed_by like  '%$search%' or   purpose like  '%$search%' or file_name like '%$search%' order by date desc limit $page_start_from, $total_num_page";

                                            }
                                            else
                                            {

                    $p_query="select * from files order by date desc limit $page_start_from, $total_num_page";
                                            }
                          $p_run=mysqli_query($con,$p_query);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($p_run)){
                             while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($p_run))
                             {
                                $c_id=$row['id'];
                                $file=$row['file_name'];
                                $purpose=$row['purpose'];
                                $recieve=$row['recieved_by'];
                                $processed=$row['processed_by'];
                                $address=$row['address'];
                                $contact=$row['contact_no'];
                                $date=$row['date'];


                            ?>
```

and here is pagination code for sending

```
<ul class="pagination">
                      <?php
                        for($i=1;$i<=$total_page;$i++)
                          echo "<li class='".($page_id == $i? 'active' : '')."'><a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>$i</a></li>";
                      ?>

                  </ul>
```

So where should i write the code to unset the session ,Help me please , i am new in php , and i know that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Use after which va\riable you want to destroy you session

> unset($SESSION['key'])